# English translation of Bourbaki's Theory of Sets differs from French

Tags: elementary-set-theory

While reading Bourbaki's Theory of Sets in English, I came across something which seems to be inconsistent. On page 19, the discussion on Formative Constructions starts thus: (1.) "Some of the specific signs of a theory are called *relational*, and the others are called *substantific*." The fact is that this sentence is absent in French edition of the book.

The difficulty arises when it says: (2.) "An assembly is said to be of the *first species* if it begins with a τ, or with a *substantific* sign, or if it consists of a single letter; otherwise it is of the *second species*."

And On line 4 of the next page it says: (3.) "The assemblies of the first species (resp. of the second species) *which appear in the formative constructions of T* are called *terms* (resp. *relations*) in T."

(I numbered the quotes for convenience)

My questions are:

a. Does "resp." mean 'respectively'? And does respectively in this case mean 'in order?'

b. If yes, then, the order changed between quotes 1 and 3. Is there any reason for it? Am I reading it incorrectly, or my copy of the book contains an error?

c. If you allow me I would like to make a supplementary question. In page 19, condition (b) of Formative Constructions states that "(b) There is in the sequence an assembly **B** of the second species, preceding **A**, such that **A** is **¬B**." What I understood is thus: there would be a **B** somewhere in the assembly, and after it, there would be a **¬B**. Is this interpretation correct? Is 'B' a substantific sign, and '¬B' is relational?

I am attaching pictures of both versions here.
[English](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfKEa.png)
[French](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq7jD.png)

Comment: Are you sure the English translation is a translation of the same edition you are looking up in French?

Comment: Both are from Springer. English translation is "reprint of the original edition <2004>" and the French is "Réimpression inchangée de l'édition originale de 1970," copyrighted in 2006.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to your first question are both *yes*: assemblies of the first species are called terms, and assemblies of the second species are called relations.

The authors may have had one, but I see no good reason for the change. Given that they intended to use the expression *first species* for terms and the expression *second species* for relations, it would have made more sense to have reversed the order in the first sentence of the section, so that it read ‘Some of the specific signs of the theory are called *substantific*, and the others are called *relational*.

I interpret (b) on page 19 the same way you do. However, $\boldsymbol{B}$ is required to be of the second species, so it must be a relation; in any case it’s an assembly that is not a single letter, not a specific sign, so it can’t be substantific (if I understand the definitions correctly). $\neg\boldsymbol{B}$ is also a relation.